# Interacting with expressjs on another server throwing Access-Control-Allow-Headers errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, chat

I am trying to implement Spika web chat ([http://spikaapp.com/][1]) on my Amazon server. I have my website code on one server instance and Spika chat server on another server instance. Spika chat server is up and running. Now when I try to interact with the server on my website I get this error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:8000/spika/v1/user/list/Boom?_=1468157726669.
Request header field access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
in preflight response.
```

Earlier I had the CORS error I resolved it referring this : http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Now I can login but my client but soon after login I get the above error. My current expressjs API handler code for enabling CORS :

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        next();
    });
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to make a https ajax request. https ajax request is different from http ajax. Please google on making https ajax request. Two requests needs to made: pre-flight request asking server permission followed by the actual request if server is ok.

Answer (score 2):

The **server** (that the POST request is sent to) needs to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header (etc) **in its response**. Putting them in your request from the client has no effect.

This is because it is up to the server to specify that it accepts cross-origin requests (and that it permits the `Content-Type` request header, and so on) – the client cannot decide for itself that a given server should allow CORS.

When you start playing around with custom request headers you will get a CORS preflight. This is a request that uses the HTTP `OPTIONS` verb and includes several headers, one of which being `Access-Control-Request-Headers` listing the headers the client wants to include in the request.

You need to reply to that CORS preflight with the appropriate CORS headers to make this work. One of which is indeed `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. That header needs to contain the same values the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header contained (or more).

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol explains this setup in more detail.

Comment: the code I shared is put up on server not client. expressjs runs on server end. Do I have to do something on client end too?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors. Thanks for all your help guys :)